# Display WooCommerce Memberships price for non members

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, woocommerce-memberships

I'm using the [WooCommerce Membership](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/#) plugin to display member discounts on the Product page. Now I want to display the discount you could get with a membership for non member.

**This is what I see when I'm not a member:**

[image: This is what i see when i'm not a member]

**This is what I see when I'm a member:**

[image: This is what I see when I'm a member]

> **This is what I want to see when I'm not a member:**
>
> [image: This is what i want to see when i'm not a member]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you manage to do something?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

```
 echo wc_memberships()->get_member_discounts_instance() >get_product_discount($product->id);
```

with this code you can find the discount.

let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm amazed how many times this question has been asked on the web and still no answer. Here's the solution I was able to come up with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'neonbrand_show_member_price_non_members' );
function neonbrand_show_member_price_non_members($price) {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $variations = $product->WC_Product_Variable::get_available_variations();
        $variations_id = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'variation_id' );

        if ( ! wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( get_current_user_id(), 'vip-membership' ) ) {
            $a = get_option( 'wc_memberships_rules' );
            foreach($a as $value) {
                if(!empty(array_intersect($variations_id, $value['object_ids']))) {
                    $discount = $value['discount_amount'];
                    $nonmember_price = $product->get_price();
                    $member_price[] = $nonmember_price - $discount;
                }
            }
            echo '<p class="price"><b><i>Member Price As Low As: $'.min($member_price).'</i></b></p>';
        }
    }
}
```

I have variations on most products so that's why I had to implement the "Member Price As Low As" because the variations had different discounts. Obviously the incentive for all of this is to get people to become members.

[image]

This should be a feature of the plugin IMO. But ‍♂️